# Prevent component as array element from re-render when the parent array changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a simple files uploader, I have `listOfFiles` coming from dropzone drag and drop already.

A simple loop over the files

```
{listOfFiles.map((file, i) => (
  <SingleFile
    key={i}
    index={i}
    file={file}
    handleDelete={handleDelete}
  />
))}
```

Inside of `SingleFile` I do `axios` API calls to upload the file when the component mount using `useEffect` simplified as this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!props.file) return;
  // ...
    // Axios call and bunch of states changes.
  // ...
}, [props.file]);
```

Upload process is just fine & When I do drag another files it works, New files added to `listOfFiles` and then start uploading.

Now when I click on the delete button inside `SingleFile`, `handleDelete` on parent component fires to delete the files with the specific index.

```
<button onClick={props.handleDelete(index)}> Delete </button>
```

on `handleDelete`

```
setListOfFiles((listOfFiles) => listOfFiles.filter((f, i) => i !== index));
```

Now the problem is when I delete a `SingleFile` the `listOfFiles` array is updated and each array element which is a `SingleFile` component is re-rendered and the upload `axios` call is called again... etc.

Is there any way to not re-render an Instance of component when another instance changes? to make it depends only on it's state/props when it comes to re-render? and to control it's mount/unmount by unique id or index in the parent array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely re-rendering because the `key` on each `SingleFile` component is just the index of the corresponding item in the `listOfFiles` array. React uses `key` to keep track of which item is which when a list of components is rendered. So if you have:

```js
const listOfFiles = [
  'file0',
  'file1',
  'file2',
  'file3',
]
```

You'd have these compoments:

```js
<SingleFile key=0 file='file0' />
<SingleFile key=1 file='file1' />
<SingleFile key=2 file='file2' />
<SingleFile key=3 file='file3' />
```

The key is just the index from the array. So if you remove let's say the second element (i.e. element with index 1, 'file1'), then react will think that all the elements after it have changed (because they now have different data). You end up with this array:

```js
const listOfFiles = [
  'file0',
  // 'file1', // this element was removed
  'file2',
  'file3',
]
```

And these compoments:

```js
<SingleFile key=0 file='file0' />
<SingleFile key=1 file='file2' />
<SingleFile key=2 file='file3' />
```

See how keys 1 and 2 now have `file2` and `file3`, where before they had `file1` and `file2`? React now thinks that the components with keys 1 and 2 have changed, and will re-render. Also, since `file` has changed, your `useEffect` call will be run again.

The solution is to set the key to something unique to each file, something that won't change if one of the files is deleted. The file name could potentially be that:

```js
{listOfFiles.map((file, i) => (
  <SingleFile
    key={file.name}
    index={i}
    file={file}
    handleDelete={handleDelete}
  />
))}
```

Though there's a chance multiple files could have the same name, and React doesn't allow duplicate keys. A potentially better solution is to add a timestamp of when the file was uploaded (in microseconds) and include that in your `file` object. There's still a chance of duplicates, but much less likely:

```js
{listOfFiles.map((file, i) => (
  <SingleFile
    key={file.uploadedStamp}
    index={i}
    file={file}
    handleDelete={handleDelete}
  />
))}
```

Actually, maybe even a better solution is to just add a random value as a unique id for each file, when it's uploaded. Then use that unique id as your `key`:

```js
{listOfFiles.map((file, i) => (
  <SingleFile
    key={file.id}
    index={i}
    file={file}
    handleDelete={handleDelete}
  />
))}
```

You might also want to use that id to identify the file yourself, instead of using `index`:

```js
{listOfFiles.map((file) => (
  <SingleFile
    key={file.id}
    id={file.id}
    file={file}
    handleDelete={handleDelete}
  />
))}
```

Then your button and `handleDelete` would look something like this:

```js
<button onClick={() => props.handleDelete(props.id)}> Delete </button>
```

```js
const handleDelete = (idToRemove) => {
  setListOfFiles(listOfFiles.filter((f) => f.id !== idToRemove));
}
```