# In React, how to avoid unnecessary rerender when array used for rendering changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072941/prevent-component-as-array-element-from-re-render-when-the-parent-array-changes), the solution is to use an unique value instead of index of map as the 'key' prop when looping through the array to render components. However, it not working for me as the remaning components still rerender after i delete an element from the array. What am i missing here?

Here is my attempts，which is not working as expected：

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Column from "./Column.js";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "lebron",
      age: 36,
      team: "lakers"
    },
    {
      name: "chris",
      age: 36,
      team: "suns"
    },
    {
      name: "james",
      age: 32,
      team: "nets"
    }
  ];
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(data);
  const handleClick = () => {
    return function () {
      const p = [...players];
      p.splice(0, 1);
      setPlayers(p);
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
          <td>team</td>
        </tr>
        {players.map((p) => (
          <Column key={p.name} player={p} onClick={handleClick(p.name)} />
        ))}
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleClick()}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Column.js:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Column({ player, onClick }) {
  console.log(player.name, "update", Date());
  return (
      <tr>
        <td>{player.name}</td>
        <td>{player.age}</td>
        <td>{player.team}</td>
      </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are changing the state of your component which causes a re-render. The only think I would say would be to move your data array outside of your component so it doesn't get defined each re-render

Comment: You need to memoize the Column component. https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html but you need to have some react performance background.

Comment: I have to say that your handleClick function is not right. When you use splice you are modifyng the players array and in React state must be modified only using the dispatch function (setPlayers). In your case, you should use .filter method because it returns a new Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default React behavior.

The children updates because an update on the father state occurred.

If you want to re-render child components *only if* the props has changed you need to wrap your child component with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) HOC.

Briefly, with `React.memo` React renders your component the first time, memoize the result and then reuse the last rendered result (skipping unnecessary re-renders).

React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component wrapped in `React.memo` has a `useState`, `useReducer` or `useContext` Hook in its implementation, it will still re-render when state or context change.

In your case:

*Column.js file*

```
import { memo } from "react";

function Column({ player, onClick }) {
  console.log(`Render player ${player.name}`);
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{player.name}</td>
      <td>{player.age}</td>
      <td>{player.team}</td>
      <button onClick={() => onClick(player)}>Delete</button>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default memo(Column);
```

*App.js file*

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Column from "./Column";

const data = [
  {
    name: "lebron",
    age: 36,
    team: "lakers"
  },
  {
    name: "chris",
    age: 36,
    team: "suns"
  },
  {
    name: "james",
    age: 32,
    team: "nets"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(data);
  const handleClick = useCallback((deleted) => {
    setPlayers((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((player) => player.name !== deleted.name)
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
          <td>team</td>
        </tr>
        {players.map((p) => (
          <Column key={p.name} player={p} onClick={handleClick} />
        ))}
      </table>
      {/* This button makes no sense */}
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(players[0])}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-platform-jsiuz?file=/src/App.js)

I make a few changes in your code:

- `handleClick` function is not right. When you use `splice` you are **modifyng** the players array and in React state must be modified only using the dispatch function (**setPlayers**). In your case, you should use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method because it returns a new Array.

  ```
  const handleClick = (deleted) => {
    setPlayers((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((player) => player.name !== deleted.name)
    );
  };
  ```
- wrap your `Column` component with React.memo HOC.

```js
   export default React.memo(Column);
```

- wrap your `handleClick` function with [useCallback](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). This is because you need to memoize your function due to you are using React.memo.

  ```
  const handleClick = useCallback((deleted) => {
    setPlayers((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((player) => player.name !== deleted.name)
    );
  }, []);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your problem

```
import { useState } from "react";
function Column({ player, onClick }) {
  console.log(player.name, "update", Date());
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{player.name}</td>
      <td>{player.age}</td>
      <td>{player.team}</td>
      <td onClick={onClick}>x</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      name: "lebron",
      age: 36,
      team: "lakers"
    },
    {
      name: "chris",
      age: 36,
      team: "suns"
    },
    {
      name: "james",
      age: 32,
      team: "nets"
    }
  ];
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(data);
  const handleClick = (index) => {
    return function () {
      if(index===-1)
      return setPlayers([])
      const p = [...players];
      p.splice(index, 1);
      setPlayers(p);
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>age</td>
          <td>team</td>
        </tr>
        {players.map((p, index) => (
          <Column key={p.name} player={p} onClick={handleClick(index)} />
        ))}
      </table>
     <p> Click x to delete</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick(0)}>Delete First</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick(players.length-1)}>Delete Last</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick(-1)}>Delete All</button>

    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sky-77bwz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you want to delete the last element of your Array for that there is the pop() method

- And not call directly function in onClick
- Also use thead and tbody in your table

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    const p = [...players];
    p.pop();
    setPlayers(p);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>age</td>
            <td>team</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {players.map((p) => (
            <Column
              key={p.name}
              player={p}
              onClick={() => handleClick(p.name)}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
```